# .fadein with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how I can make this bit of code have a .fadein property?  Preferably .fadein medium speed would be the best.  Thanks!

```
<script>
function LinkOnClick4(box) {
$('#friendresults').load('conversation.php?id=' + box);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First hide the element, load it's contents, and then use the callback function of the `load` function to fade it back in:

```
function LinkOnClick4(box) {

    //select our element to populate, hide it, load in the new content, then once the new content is loaded, fade it back in
    $('#friendresults').hide().load('conversation.php?id=' + box, function () {
        $(this).fadeIn(750);
    });
}
```

If you want the element to keep its space in the page (not totally disappear) then you can just set it's opacity rather than using the `.hide()` and `.fadeIn()` functions:

```
function LinkOnClick4(box) {

    //select our element to populate, hide it, load in the new content, then once the new content is loaded, fade it back in
    $('#friendresults').css({ opacity : 0 }).load('conversation.php?id=' + box, function () {
        $(this).fadeTo(1, 750);
    });
}
```

The difference between the two code-blocks is that the first one will allow elements relatively positioned around the `#friendresults` element to shift when it's hidden, and the second code-block keeps the page from shifting around when the `#friendresults` element is hidden/shown.

Some docs if you need more help:

- `.hide()`: http://api.jquery.com/hide
- `.fadeIn()`: http://api.jquery.com/fadein
- `.fadTo()`: http://api.jquery.com/fadeto
- `.css()`: http://api.jquery.com/css

Comment: This is probably the best approach; gonna delete mine :).

Answer (score 1):

Style #friendresults to be hidden then call

```
$('#friendresults').load('conversation.php?id=' + box, function() {
  $('#friendresults').fadeIn()
});
```